# What is the "TLS_GREASE_BA" cypher in TLS?

Tags: ssl, tls, cryptography

I've just ran a client test on SSL Labs Client Tester and my client reports as the favourite cipher suite a cypher named `TLS_GREASE_BA` with a null key length.

What is this cipher suite supposed to do? Google search yields (at least for me) two results on some German site and the only reason the cipher is listed is because someone posted their client cipher support list.

Comment: A quick Google found this https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/google-wants-grease-chrome/

Comment: So essentially a way of making server-side implementations fail if they don't implement TLS correctly.